# How to make a linux driver detect and use a device after linux kernel has already loaded?

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, embedded-linux, xilinx, i2c

I am using a System Monitor device at address 0x3f on i2c-0 bus. This device is configured with the pmbus driver in the device tree.

The problem is that, this 'Sysmon' device is not powered when the linux kernel is loaded. Therefore, when I do a i2cdetect on bus 0 we see '--' at 0x3f which is expected. Now, when I power the Sysmon using my UI, the device is added by linux and we see a '3f' on running the i2cdetect.

Now, I want the pmbus driver to detect this device and change it to 'UU' so that I can see all the pmbus attributes in sysfs.

Can I do it from userspace and how? If no, can you suggest how can I tackle this.

If I force power the device using hardware and then load linux, the pmbus driver detects this device and reserves it. But I'm not allowed to force power the device.

Device Tree:

```
   i2c@ff020000 

   {

        compatible = "cdns,i2c-r1p14", "cdns,i2c-r1p10";
        status = "okay";
        interrupt-parent = <0x4>;
        interrupts = <0x0 0x11 0x4>;
        reg = <0x0 0xff020000 0x0 0x1000>;
        #address-cells = <0x1>;
        #size-cells = <0x0>;
        power-domains = <0x15>;
        clocks = <0x3 0x3d>;
        clock-frequency = <0x186a0>;
        pinctrl-names = "default", "gpio";
        pinctrl-0 = <0x16>;
        pinctrl-1 = <0x17>;
        scl-gpios = <0x18 0x4a 0x0>;
        sda-gpios = <0x18 0x4b 0x0>;

        fpga1sysmon0@3f {
            compatible = "general,pmbus";
            reg = <0x3f>;
        };
```

PS: I'm a beginner and this is my 1st question on Stack Overflow. Please bear with me for any mistakes I've made.

Comment: I don’t know what PM bus is, I guess power management for some ARM SoCs, but I would recommend to see how it’s done for existing hardware. And I suspect that the device should have a phandle to the i2c master.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about enabling the sysmon in `/etc/init.d/rcS` (assuming you are using busybox init) or in systemd `/etc/rc.local`.

the following will load the driver for an **LTC2978** at address **0x60**
on I2C bus #1:

```
$ modprobe pmbus
$ echo ltc2978 0x60 > /sys/bus/i2c/devices/i2c-1/new_device
```

you can put that in

`/etc/init.d/rcS` or `/etc/rc.local`

see also
https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/hwmon/pmbus